# Parse IP and Download-Total from mikrotik

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I wanna extract IP and download-total from mikrotik command `/queue simple print stat`
Here's some example :

```
0    name="101" target=192.168.10.101/32 rate=0bps/0bps total-rate=0bps 
  packet-rate=0/0 total-packet-rate=0 queued-bytes=0/0 
  total-queued-bytes=0 queued-packets=0/0 total-queued-packets=0 
  bytes=17574842/389197663 total-bytes=0 packets=191226/308561 
  total-packets=0 dropped=9/5899 total-dropped=0 

1    name="102" target=192.168.10.102/32 rate=0bps/0bps total-rate=0bps 
  packet-rate=0/0 total-packet-rate=0 queued-bytes=0/0 
  total-queued-bytes=0 queued-packets=0/0 total-queued-packets=0 
  bytes=65593392/183786457 total-bytes=0 packets=163260/166022 
  total-packets=0 dropped=175/2403 total-dropped=0 

2    name="103" target=192.168.10.103/32 rate=0bps/0bps total-rate=0bps 
  packet-rate=0/0 total-packet-rate=0 queued-bytes=0/0 
  total-queued-bytes=0 queued-packets=0/0 total-queued-packets=0 
  bytes=3263234/67407044 total-bytes=0 packets=41437/52602 
  total-packets=0 dropped=0/546 total-dropped=0
```

All that I need is :

```
192.168.10.101 389197663  
192.168.10.102 183786457
192.168.10.103 67407044
```

But I get

```
target=192.168.10.101/32
bytes=17574842/389197663
target=192.168.10.102/32
bytes=65593392/183786457
target=192.168.10.103/32
bytes=3263234/67407044
```

I try it with `grep -oP 'target=.*?\ |[^\-]bytes=.*?\ ' | sed 's/^ //g'`. 
So, how can I parse it?  Sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue your line of parsing with another pipes  (most easy way i think)

```
grep -oP 'target=.*?\ |[^\-]bytes=.*?\ ' file | sed 's/^ //g' | sed -r 's/target=([^/]*)[/].*/\1/; s/bytes=[^/]*[/]//' | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

output

```
192.168.10.101 389197663 
192.168.10.102 183786457 
192.168.10.103 67407044
```

Comment: THANKS!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've spent a lot of hour to do this.. And now you came and It's all work like a charm!! Thank you so much sir :D

Comment: np, tricky part is last sed which concatanete pair of lines, maybe all with grep could be done. Lot of ways for solving when dealing with problems. I'm glad it worked.

Comment: right! that was the tricky part when I have to concatanete those 2 line :D
btw, one more.. thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[0-9]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}name/,/^[[:blank:]]*$/ {
   /^[0-9]/{ 
      s#.*target=\([^/]*\).*#\1#;h;d
      }
   \#^[[:blank:]]*bytes=[0-9]*/\([0-9]*\).*# !d
   s//\1/
   G
   s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/p
   }
   d
   ' YourFile
```

A bit long but do the job in 1 sed

```
awk '{
   if ( $3 ~ /target=/ ) split( $3, aIP, "[=/]")
   if ( $1 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*bytes=[0-9]*/ ) {
      split( $1, aByt, "/")
      print aIP[2] " " aByt[2]
      }
   }' YourFile
```

same in awk

if always same exact structure

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="" }
     { split( $3, aIP, "[=/]"); split( $12, aByt, "/")
       print aIP[2] " " aByt[2]
     }' YourFile
```